# Android unable to start Activity null pointer exception at listview setadapter

Tags: android, listview, android-arrayadapter

This activity is a duplicate of one that functions. I cannot find my error. I have also searched extensively without success. This is my first app and any help would be greatly appreciated. the error occurs at the list view set adapter
in the main activity

```
     package com.example.jaclen.queensdreambook;

     import android.app.Activity;
     import android.os.Bundle;
     import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
     import android.widget.ListView;



    public class bMainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_b_main);
    ListView listViewbwlo = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.ListViewbwlo);

        ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(

                this, R.array.bw, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1);

          listViewbwlo.setAdapter(adapter);

    }

}
```

Layout xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>


<LinearLayout

    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#DAA520">




      <ListView
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="match_parent"
          android:id="@+id/listViewbwlo"
          android:divider="#000000"
          android:dividerHeight="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin">



          </ListView>


</LinearLayout>
```

Manifest
    
    
        android:versionCode="1"
        android:versionName="1.0" >

```
    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name=".QueenActivityMainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >

            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>

        </activity>


        <activity
            android:name=".ainfoMainActivity"
            android:label="Queens Dream Book"
            android:parentActivityName=".QueenActivityMainActivity" >

           <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.example.jaclen.queensdreambook.ainfoMainActivity" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
           </intent-filter>

            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
                android:value="com.example.jaclen.queensdreambook.QueenActivityMainActivity" />

        </activity>


        <activity
            android:name=".bMainActivity"
            android:label="@string/QueensDreamBook"
            android:parentActivityName=".QueenActivityMainActivity" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.example.jaclen.queensdreambook.bMainActivity" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>

            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
                android:value="com.example.jaclen.queensdreambook.QueenActivityMainActivity" />
        </activity>
```

Logcat

```
03-24 15:21:03.080  12337-12337/com.example.jaclen.queensdreambook I/System.out﹕ Sending WAIT chunk
03-24 15:21:03.280  12337-12337/com.example.jaclen.queensdreambook I/System.out﹕ Debugger has connected
03-24 15:21:03.280  12337-12337/com.example.jaclen.queensdreambook I/System.out﹕ Debugger has connected
1:03.480  12337-12337/com.example.jaclen.queensdreambook I/System.out﹕ `enter code here`waiting for debugger to settle...
1:03.690  12337-12337/com.example.jaclen.queensdreambook I/System.out﹕ waiting for debugger to settle...
03-24 15:21:04.892  12337-12337/com.example.jaclen.queensdreambook I/System.out﹕ debugger has settled (1441)
4 15:21:06.073  12337-12337/com.example.jaclen.queensdreambook I/Adreno200-EGLSUB﹕ <ConfigWindowMatch:2218>: Format RGBA_8888.
12337/com.example.jaclen.queensdreambook D/memalloc﹕ ion: Mapped buffer base:0x5bd9c000 size:1536000 offset:0 fd:58
03-24 15:21:06.103  12337-12337/com.example.jaclen.queensdreambook E/﹕ Can't open file for reading
03-24 15:21:06.113  12337-12337/com.example.jaclen.queensdreambook E/﹕ Can't open file for reading
03-24 15:21:06.964  12337-12337/com.example.jaclen.queensdreambook D/memalloc﹕ ion: Mapped buffer base:0x5c28d000 size:1536000 offset:0 fd:62
03-24 15:21:07.014  12337-12337/com.example.jaclen.queensdreambook D/memalloc﹕ ion: Mapped buffer base:0x5c414000 size:1536000 offset:0 fd:65
03-24 15:28:27.544  12337-12337/com.example.jaclen.queensdreambook W/dalvikvm﹕ threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40d01210)
03-24 15:28:27.564  12337-12337/com.example.jaclen.queensdreambook E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.jaclen.queensdreambook/com.example.jaclen.queensdreambook.bMainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1956)
           at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1981)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:123)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1147)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4428)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:787)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:554)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
     Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
            at com.example.jaclen.queensdreambook.bMainActivity.onCreate(bMainActivity.java:25)
            at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:4465)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1049)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1920)
           at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1981)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:123)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1147)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4428)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:787)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:554)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: You have `R.id.ListViewbwlo` while your id in xml is   `android:id="@+id/listViewbwlo"`

Comment: How does it even got compiled ? There has to be some view with caps 'L'  - ListViewbwlo .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Try this.**

**Change this part**

```
 ListView listViewbwlo = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.ListViewbwlo);
```

**To this**

```
 ListView listViewbwlo = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listViewbwlo);
```

Looks like you have taken wrong id.

Comment: Thank you both for the solution to this issue. I have chased my tail for two weeks on this typo. I think it's time for an eye exam.

Comment: @R.Jackson Please check mark this as right answer thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

In your XML file you take `listview` and give id like this

```
android: id="@+id/listViewbwlo"
```

In you Activitie file when you get the `listview` using `findviewById()` you give id wrong because java is a case sensitive language so correct statement like

```
ListView listViewbwlo=(ListView)findviewById(R.id.listViewbwlo);
```

That's way you not get error at compile time otherwise you get the error at compile time. Because at that time id not fond and give the error.